# Argument of type "LPCWSTR" is incompatible of the parameter of type "LPCSTR"

Tags: c++, lpcwstr

Can somebody please tell me why i'm getting an error.  I've been trying to figure this out for a bit now.

```
LPCWSTR drive2[4] = { L"C:\\", L"D:\\", L"E:\\", L"F:\\" };
int i;
UINT test;

for (i = 0; i<12; i++)        
{                         
    test = GetDriveType(drive2[i]); //anything from here with "drive2[i]" is an error.

    switch (test)
    {                          
    case 0: ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], "0 cannot be determined", MB_OK);
        break;                                                                       
    case 1: ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], "1 invalid", MB_OK);
        break;                                                                                     
    case 2: ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], "2 removable", MB_OK);
        break;                                                                                    
    case 3: ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], "3 fixed", MB_OK);
        break;  
    default: "Unknown value!\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LPCWSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) is an alias for `const wchar_t*`.

You are using the `TCHAR` version of the `GetDriveType()` and `MessageBox()` functions.  `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` if `UNICODE` is defined at compile-time, otherwise it maps to `char`.

Your `drive2` variable is an array of `wchar_t` pointers, so in order to pass `drive2[i]` as-is to `GetDriveType()` and `MessageBox()`, you have to compile your project for Unicode (ie, make the `UNICODE` conditional be defined at compile-time), which will make `GetDriveType()` map to [`GetDriveTypeW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) and `MessageBox()` map to [`MessageBoxW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) so that they accept only *wide* (`wchar_t`) strings.  Otherwise, `GetDriveType()` will map to [`GetDriveTypeA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) and `MessageBox()` will map to [`MessageBoxA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa) so they accept only *narrow* (`char`) strings.

You are passing *narrow* string literals to `MessageBox()`, which will not work when compiling for Unicode.  And you can't pass *wide* strings to `TCHAR` functions if you are NOT compiling for Unicode - which sounds like the case in your situation, as the error message is complaining about passing a `const wchar_t*` pointer to a `const char*` parameter.

You need to use the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro to make string literals be *wide* when `UNICODE` is defined, instead of being *narrow*.

I would also suggest using `TEXT()` for the string literals in your `drive2` array as well, to match the `TCHAR` functions that you are passing the array elements to.

Also, your loop is going out of bounds of the `drive2` array.

With that said, try this:

```cpp
LPCTSTR drive2[4] = { TEXT("C:\\"), TEXT("D:\\"), TEXT("E:\\"), TEXT("F:\\") };
int i;
UINT test;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)        
{                         
    test = GetDriveType(drive2[i]);

    switch (test)
    {                          
        case 0:
            ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], TEXT("0 cannot be determined"), MB_OK);
            break;                                                                       
        case 1:
            ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], TEXT("1 invalid"), MB_OK);
            break;                                                                                     
        case 2:
            ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], TEXT("2 removable"), MB_OK);
            break;                                                                                    
        case 3:
            ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], TEXT("3 fixed"), MB_OK);
            break;  
        default:
            ::MessageBox(Handle, drive2[i], TEXT("Unknown value!"), MB_OK);
            break;  
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to deal exclusively with `wchar_t` (which you should be), then use the Unicode-based function definitions directly, and use *wide* string literals only, don't deal with `TCHAR` at all:

```cpp
LPCWSTR drive2[4] = { L"C:\\", L"D:\\", L"E:\\", L"F:\\" };
int i;
UINT test;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)        
{                         
    test = GetDriveTypeW(drive2[i]);

    switch (test)
    {                          
        case 0:
            ::MessageBoxW(Handle, drive2[i], L"0 cannot be determined", MB_OK);
            break;                                                                       
        case 1:
            ::MessageBoxW(Handle, drive2[i], L"1 invalid", MB_OK);
            break;                                                                                     
        case 2:
            ::MessageBoxW(Handle, drive2[i], L"2 removable", MB_OK);
            break;                                                                                    
        case 3:
            ::MessageBoxW(Handle, drive2[i], L"3 fixed", MB_OK);
            break;  
        default:
            ::MessageBoxW(Handle, drive2[i], L"Unknown value!", MB_OK);
            break;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LPCSTR` is `const char*`, while `LPCWSTR` is `const wchar_t*`, and they are not compatible.

Wide string declaration in C++:
`LPCWSTR string = L"Wide string";`

Regular string:
`LPCSTR string = "Regular string";`

If you want to use wide strings, you need to use the `W` version, in your case, use `GetDriveTypeW`.

Note that the `GetDriveType` is not a function, it is a MACRO that expands to `GetDriveTypeA` if your code is compiled in ASCII mode (default), but expands to `GetDriveTypeW` if the code is compiled in UNICODE mode

Comment: You don't need to use the `W` versions explicitly if `UNICODE` is defined, and it _should_ be defined for all new projects. (Though UTF-8 support is picking up...)

Comment: It is not defined by default as far as I know. You should define it in project properties or add the corresponding flag.

EDIT: I just checked and the default is still Multi-byte (ASCII)

Comment: I think it is safest to explicitly use the W or A version, depending upon your intent. Then you don't have to assume anything.